# How to retrieve or download SharePoint empty user profile picture?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, json-formatting, person-or-group

I would like to know is there a way to download or retrieve SharePoint empty user profile picture?

For example: If you use a person column in SharePoint and get the picture from everybody. The persons who doesn't have a picture SharePoint displays a sample Image.

How can I get that image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below steps:

1. Create a new blank SharePoint list
2. Create a Person or Group column in new SharePoint list
3. Choose to Show profile photos from column settings like:

   [image]
4. Add one item in the list and select user in person column who does not have profile picture
5. Use browser developer tools to inspect the empty user profile picture like below and you will get the image URL:

   [image]
6. Hover on image URL and then click on URL in hover popup, it will open image in new tab
7. Right (Second) click on image and use "Save image as.." option to download the image.

---

I have downloaded below empty user profile image from our SharePoint online tenant. If you want you can download it from below, upload it in your SharePoint site and use it as per your requirements:

[image]